# How can I test that a field is set to a certain value?

Tags: groovy, field, spock, getter-setter

This seems basic so I'm expecting this to be a dupe... but I haven't found anything that answers this question.

My app code is also Groovy. Say I have a field

```
def something
```

and in my test (where the CUT is a Spock `Spy`) I run a method in the middle of which there is a line

```
something = null
```

or

```
something = new Bubble()
```

... I'm simply trying to find a way of testing that something has indeed been set to `null` (or any value...)

In my `then` block I've tried:

```
1 * spyCUT.setSomething( null )
```

and

```
1 * spyCUT.setSomething(_)
```

and

```
1 * spyCUT.set( 'something', _ )
```

Incidentally, in answer to the objection that I could just test the value of `something` in the `then` block, the situation is that `something` is meant to be set first to one value and then to another in the course of this method...

Having read *Groovy In Action 2nd Ed* I have the vaguest of notions about how Groovy goes about dealing with getting and setting fields... Not enough, clearly.

**MCVE (FWIW!)**

```
class Spocko {
    def something

    def doStuff() {
        something = 'fruit'
    }
}

class SpockoTest extends Specification {
    def 'test it'(){
        given:
        Spocko spySpocko = Spy( Spocko )

        when:
        spySpocko.doStuff()

        then:
        1 * spySpocko.setSomething(_)
    }
}
```

**LATER** (after kriegaex's very helpful reply)

With above `SpockTest` where `setSomething` *is* invoked:

```
class Spocko {
    def something

    def doStuff() {
        this.each{
            it.something = 'fruit' 
        }
    }
}
```

... passes! I'm trying now to understand why...

Incidentally I also find that the following passes (and doesn't without the closure):

```
1 * spySpocko.setProperty( 'something', _ )
```

Comment: With all due respect and no offense meant: Mike, when will you finally learn to provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s with your questions? This really isn't fun, I always have to piece together reproduceable test cases from your incoherent sets of snippets. Help others to help you, improve your style of asking questions - please, please. P.S.: You read a lot of specs and tool source codes, trying to do tricky things. Why? Keep it simple, use clean code and make your code testable. You will enjoy the results and save tons of time, I promise.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for the response. But... providing an MCVE in this case would be silly: the MCVE is explicit in what I describe: you can do with one 10-line Groovy app file and one 10-line Spock testing file.  You could even put them in the same file.  But you're not obliged to answer anything anyway.  Or you could just believe that I get the results I describe (in the simplest imaginable case).

Comment: I don't know what you mean about "tricky things".  As I develop this project I am spinning tests (specifications/features) driven by a very "stringent" TDD logic: I want my app classes to do something which they don't already do, and ask myself how to "pose" that problem.  Most of my tests are not actually unit tests, they are more like functional tests, and development is grindingly incremental, never "radical".  If you don't like the questions I ask the best thing is to ignore them...

Comment: Perhaps more to the point, with regard to this specific point, the question is a simple one: can Spock apply mocking to methods which are generated at run time? (AST methods - at least I think getters and setters fall into this category...?).  It is not unreasonable to want to test this.  It may or may not be possible, but I don't think it counts as inherently "tricky".

Comment: See? It wasn't so hard to privide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you have made it very easy for me to answer your question. Thank you. :-) Why write three comments about why you don't want to improve your question? This is not my personal idea, the MCVE link (if you ever opened it) is a StackOverflow guide on how to ask questions here. How ever much prose you write to describe the problem, it is only supporting your case, but prone to misunderstanding. Let the code speak!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I have seen your MCVE, the question can be answered as follows: You cannot test for a method call which never happens. `doStuff()` just assigns a value to a field, it does not call a setter method internally. Look at this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Specification

class SpockoTest extends Specification {
  static class Spocko {
    def something

    def doStuff() {
      something = 'fruit'
    }

    def doMoreStuff() {
      setSomething('vegetable')
    }
  }

  def 'test it'(){
    given: 'Spocko spy'
    Spocko spySpocko = Spy(Spocko)

    when: 'calling method assigning value to property'
    spySpocko.doStuff()

    then: 'no setter is called'
    0 * spySpocko.setSomething(_)
    spySpocko.something == 'fruit'

    when: 'calling method using setter'
    spySpocko.doMoreStuff()

    then: 'setter gets called'
    1 * spySpocko.setSomething('vegetable')

    when: 'using Groovy setter-like syntax from another class'
    spySpocko.something = 'fish'

    then: 'actually a setter gets called'
    1 * spySpocko.setSomething('fish')
  }
}
```

This is what happens. When calling

```
javap -v target/test-classes/de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/SpockoTest\$Spocko.class
```

you see (output shortened):

```
public java.lang.Object doStuff();
  descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=3, args_size=1
       0: invokestatic  #24                 // Method $getCallSiteArray:()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
       3: astore_1
       4: ldc           #36                 // String fruit
       6: astore_2
       7: aload_2
       8: aload_0
       9: swap
      10: putfield      #38                 // Field something:Ljava/lang/Object;
      13: aload_2
      14: areturn
      15: aconst_null
      16: areturn

public java.lang.Object doMoreStuff();
  descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=3, locals=2, args_size=1
       0: invokestatic  #24                 // Method $getCallSiteArray:()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
       3: astore_1
       4: aload_1
       5: ldc           #40                 // int 0
       7: aaload
       8: aload_0
       9: ldc           #42                 // String vegetable
      11: invokeinterface #48,  3           // InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.callCurrent:(Lgroovy/lang/GroovyObject;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      16: areturn
      17: aconst_null
      18: areturn
```

Can you spot the difference?

---

**Update after question edit 2:** You wanted to know why this triggers the setter call:

```java
def doStuff() {
  this.each {
    it.something = 'fruit' 
  }
}
```

This is because `this` is provided to the closure as a parameter, thus `it.something = 'fruit'` gets resolved dynamically just like in my example `spySpocko.something = 'fish'` because it is not an internal assignment like in `something = 'fruit'` (equivalent to `this.something = 'fruit'`) anymore.

Actually I think this is not so difficult to understand even without looking at bytecode, just following the usual Groovy tutorials. I am repeating myself, but I do think you are over-engineering and over-complicating things a bit, testing things too deeply. I would not put tests like these into a production code base. Try to test the behaviour of your classes (think specifications and features!), not the innards' intricacies. But if it helps you understand how Groovy works, just continue playing.

As of now, please refrain from further question edits and follow-up questions. If you have a new problem, it would be better to create a new question with a new MCVE.

Comment: Thanks for your patience (and expertise). Yes, I can see the difference. I just did another test which I'm now going to add after the MCVE ... which uses a closure. I'm now going to try to understand this (!). I have never come across `javap`: very interesting. But my (very inexpert) understanding was that Groovy adds getter and setter AST methods at run time: clearly I have much to learn about that too...

Comment: Thanks... I am not surprised that you say that about "testing too deeply".  But what I want to do here is simply test that a open component (a Lucene `IndexWriter`) is first closed and then set to `null` before another `IndexWriter` is assigned to the field (`indexWriter`) in question.  Of course I *could* spin a method artificially called `assignIndexWriter` (or maybe `setIndexWriter` !).  It is important to set the field to `null` to allow for the possibility that opening the new `IndexWriter` fails: otherwise `indexWriter` would then be non-`null`, but assigned to a closed `IndexWriter`.

Comment: You can only test that for methods you know about - and even worse, you need to know their internal implementation. You should really have some kind of setter method (more than an auto-generated one) which enforces exactly that contract. Even better would be a final field of a wrapper type (e.g. called `IndexWriterManager`, even though that is an awful name) which takes care of the instance it manages and only accepts a new one by closing the one it currently holds first. That wrapper could be properly tested then. You do not enforce contracts by tests only.

Comment: OK thanks... useful to know your thoughts on how to look at this.